# Where can I find city area data for the US?

Tags: data, united-states, places, fips

Where can I find (on the site of a US government agency, I assume) raw data for the sizes of cities that I can programmatically process? Data indexed by FIPS place codes (i.e. those found [here](http://geonames.usgs.gov/domestic/download_data.htm)) would be optimal.

Comment: I'm on my way out but check out the US Census, and Tiger, also google should have plenty of answers, but try the dot gov websites first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download the Census Bureau's 2010 TIGER/Line shapefiles of "Places" (at the state level) through their [web interface](http://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles2010/main). All of the features have a FIPS value. I believe these shapefiles include an area field but, if not (or if the area is given in units other than what you're looking for), you can easily create a new field and have the areas calculated automatically.

If all you're looking for is a table of data, download the shapefiles and simply use the .dbf file.

Comment: Thanks, that definitely looks helpful. I'm actually not familiar with processing GIS data in shapefile format... do you know of any way to get the data in a more basic flat text format?

Comment: @jrdioko you should be able to import the .dbf file from a given shapefile (which is not a single file, as the name suggest, but a collection of a few different files sharnig the same name but different extensions) into Excel and then save it out to whatever format you'd like to work with (XLS, TXT, CSV, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You could try http://www.geonames.org/ - they have a map viewer so that you can look at the data before downloading, and a variety of ways to get the data, including an API and data dumps.

Comment: whoops, just saw the geonames link in your post. Is there a problem with Geonames data?